# DDMS not showing Device name

Tags: android, linux, ddms

DDMS is not showing up the Device information in Eclipse which is running on Ubuntu.
Also, i am not getting Logcat messages. I am getting a blank device name. I tried to reset ADB but that didn't help. How to resolve this?

[image]

Comment: Best soultion would be to restart eclipse..

Comment: @Lal That didn't helped

Comment: Try uninstalling the driver of your device and reinstalling it..

Comment: Is the `USB debugging` enabled in the device?

Comment: @Lal how to reinstall device driver in ubuntu? TDG - yes

Comment: Sorry @mssaggoo.blogspot.in not at all good in ubuntu.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Validate your device is enabled properly:

- `Settings > Developer Options` is visible. If not, you would need to enable it by finding `Build number` preference, normally in `Settings > About Device` and tap on it 7 times
- `Settings > Developer Options` - ensure `USB Debugging` is enabled
- slide down system bar and tap on `Connected as...` (normally media device or camera). Change the value to the other and see if this helps
- sometimes a simple USB cable disconnect/reconnect helps

If all above does not help, then issue in USB driver. What device are you refeering?

Comment: Open `Terminal` and write `adb devices`. If you don't see a single device, then it is a USB driver issue. What device are you using - manufacturer, model and Android OS version?